# How do I store this type of nested object in redis?

Tags: node.js, redis

```
{
    "chats": {
        "Main": {
            "3": {
                "u": "George",
                "n": "G",
                "f": "1",
                "a": "http://example.com/a.png"
            },
            "4": {
                "u": "Lisa",
                "n": "L",
                "f": "1",
                "a": "http://example.com/b.png"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I normally store this in an object in node.js

I'll also need to be able to send this data to users. An example of what I would need to do is send all of the users in a chat to a new user who signed in.

So that would simply be: `users = obj.chats.Main`

But I can't figure out how to store it in redis, let alone how I would grab data and parse it back into an object to send to a user.

This object will get fairly large as more users sign in, so let's say for example there are 100,000 users signed in at a time, maybe 20 users on each different chat.

I kind of need a set within a set to make this work, but I don't think that's possible with redis

Comment: 2019 answer: use RedisJson https://oss.redislabs.com/redisjson/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach would be to make each chat a Redis Set of users, where each user is a JSON string containing their data. Each chat might have a key like `"chat:Main"`. Then you would have another Set containing the keys of all the chats (e.g. a Set called `"chats"` with members like `"chat:Main"`, etc.).

Now, if users can appear in lots of chats, or if you want to be able to easily change individual fields for the user (e.g. change Lisa's `f` to `2`), you could represent each user as a Redis Hash instead. In that case, the sets mentioned above would contain the key to the user's hash rather than a JSON string of the data itself. That would complicate the architecture, but depending on your data and access patterns it might reduce memory use or increase efficiency.

To get the chat room information with that design you would fetch the members of the `"chat:Main"` set, and then loop through them doing a `HGETALL` on each one. By using pipelining you could do this in two Redis roundtrips (one to get the members of the chat group, and another to do all the `HGETALLs`). Or you could write a Lua script and do everything in one trip to the Redis server.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I do need to be able to change individual fields easily. But at the same time, I'll need to grab the data of all users signed into a chat and deliver it to a new user when they sign in. (the data would have to be compiled into an object). Would the method you suggested work with this?

Comment: @JDel: I've edited the answer to explain how to do that. But how do you edit individual fields with your current Javascript object? Do you loop through every chat room, looking for Lisa and changing the field each time? If you're content with that you can do the same thing with the simpler design I mentioned in the first paragraph.

Comment: Editing fields with objects is actually quite easy for me because of how everything is set up. In my situation, If a user decides to change their nickname, the function has their user ID and the chat they're signed into already. So with the object it's as easy as doing: `obj.chats[chatName][userid].n = "New Nickname";`

Comment: @JDel: If you only need to update a single user object in a single chat then the simpler solution becomes more viable. You just have to decode the JSON, set the attribute, and then reencode to JSON. Ultimately either way will work, so it's just a matter of choosing the tradeoffs that work best for your design.